# Simple checkbox not firing the jQuery code when clicked

Tags: jquery

on this page, I made a checkbox: http://www.problemio.com

The checkbox looks like this:

```
<input class="problem_follow_checkbox" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="follow_problem" /> Follow this problem
```

And in the jQuery I added this:

```
$("#problem_follow_checkbox").click (function ()
{
    alert ("clicked cvheckbox for following problem");
    var thisCheck = $(this);

    if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
    {
        // Do stuff
                alert ("yes checjed");
    }
    else
    {
        alert ("not checjed");
    }
});
```

Seems super straight forward, but for some reason when the checkbox is checked, this jQuery code does not get invoked. Any reason that might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".problem_follow_checkbox").click (function ()
{
    alert ("clicked cvheckbox for following problem");
    var thisCheck = $(this);

    if (thisCheck.is (':checked'))
    {
        // Do stuff
                alert ("yes checjed");
    }
    else
    {
        alert ("not checjed");
    }
});
```

$("#problem_follow_checkbox") is looking for the ID problem_follow_checkbox so $(".problem_follow_checkbox") will be working nice.

Comment: Or give your checkbox in ID value.

Comment: @Frederick I changed it to look like this: $(".problem_follow_checkbox").click (function ()... but for some reason the jQuery still doesn't fire. Do you think there could be anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: rename _thischeck.is (':checked')_ to _thisCheck.is (':checked')_ you are using 2 names for 1 variable

Comment: @Frederick the two names you gave are identical :) What do I rename to what?

Comment: take a look at the capital C in js variablenames are case sensitive.

Comment: @FrederickBehrends I commented out all the code in the jQuery except the initial alert and still nothing happens.  Also, there isn't an error in the JS log in Chorome - very strange.

Comment: @FrederickBehrends I see now the upper case you were talking about, but unfortunately, on my page, this still doesn't work. How do I check that my js is valid on the entire page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4201/discussion-between-frederick-behrends-and-geekedout)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use selector starting with "." if you're selecting by "class" attributed.
"#" prefix is used for selecting by id.
So, either do, as suggested above:

```
$(".problem_follow_checkbox").click( ....
```

or change your input element to something like:

```
<input id="problem_follow_checkbox"
```

and then select by

```
$("#problem_follow_checkbox").click (
```

Comment: thanks I did that, although it still doesn't fire when the checkbox is checked. Could there be something else wrong with it?

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. You define "var thisCheck" (capital C) and then call "thischeck.is" (lowercase c)